# Felica Card Error: Area or Service specified by the command cannot be accessed

Tags: nfc, smartcard, contactless-smartcard, smartcardio

I am using javax.smartcardio library to access my Felica card. I am able to get the ID of the felica card without any error. When I try to write a block to Felica card, I am getting the following status flag.

**0xA5: Area or Service specified by the command cannot be accessed.**

Here is the format of the command apdu I am using,

**FF 00 00 00  D4 40 01  08 <8 bytes of ID> 01  < number of blocks 01>  <16 bytes sof data>**

The response I am getting is:
**D5 41 00 <8 bytes of ID> 01 A5**

The **status flag2-A5** is the error specifying 'Area or Service specified by the command cannot be accessed.'

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with the Felica manufacturing team, I found that the card was empty and that's the reason I can't write/read the block.